# Crystal Reports (Ver 14) - Extracting the Last Value of an Array in Home Addresses

Tags: crystal-reports

I've been given the task of splitting addresses in a report that look like Attleboro, `MA 02703-3138`. The first and second elements are no problem for me. I capture with `split({element},",")[1]` and `split ({element}," ")[2]`. I can't get the last value with the same method. I just get blanks. Is there something I need to be doing to capture the last value of the array? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
if ubound(split({FV_VENDOR_1099_SUMMARY.PURCH_ADDR_LINE2}," ")) >= 3 
then split({FV_VENDOR_1099_SUMMARY.PURCH_ADDR_LINE2}," ")[3]
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. BTW the field is of type string if that helps anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
local stringvar array addressArray := Split({YourAddress}, " ");
addressArray[UBound(addressArray)];
```